# javascript flot multiscale common zero

Tags: javascript, flot

First: sorry for my English.

I search the possibility to set a common zero of Flot.js with activated multiscale modus.
The problem is:
I have a lot of Series with different units and Min/Max. If i use multiscale modus the Flot calculated bounds for each serie and draws this in its min/max - bounds see Image A. But I need common zero see Image B.

[image: Example Image (A|B).]

How I can set it. I found no [options](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-options) for this.

Thanks in advance.